# Using pin to connect raspberry pi to other equipment using Pybluez

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, connection, connect, pybluez

I'm trying connect a Raspberry PI to other equipment via Bluetooth using a Pybluez librarie.  It is possible to define a pin in Pybluez to connect to the equipment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You can find the answer for Bluez: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/setting-up-bluez-with-a-passkey-pin-to-be-used-as-headset-for-iphone-816003/